# Issue in parsing json object

Tags: javascript

I used an AJAX post to fetch data from the server side and I want to show it on my webpage.

That is what I have fetched:

```
{text: active    user
          active  user213123
          idle      user234234234
          loggedout  userafdadf
},
```

I want it to show the whole text after `text:`. Here is what I did: (`message` is the whole json)

```
AjaxPost: function (dataAttr, view) {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: this.url + " /user",
        datatype: "application/json",
        contentType: " text/plain",
        data: dataAttr,
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function (error) {},
        statusCode: {
            400: function (error) {
                that.processResponse(error, view);
            },
            200: function (data) {
                that.processResponse(data, view);
            }
        }
    });
},
processResponse: function (messageObj, view) {
    if (_.isUndefined(messageObj) || _.isUndefined(view)) {
        return "error";
    }
    switch (messageObj.status) {
    case 400:
        var objResponse = $.parseJSON(messageObj.responseText);
        this.processMessage(false, objResponse, view);
        break;
    default:
        this.processMessage(true, messageObj, view);
        break;
    }
},
processMessage: function (isSuccess, message, view) {
    if (_.isUndefined(isSuccess) || _.isUndefined(message) || _.isUndefined(view)) return "error";
    else {
        var outputString = "";
        var messageResponse = [];
        messageResponse = message.split(":");
        if (isSuccess) {
            output = messageResponse.split(":");
        }
        view.showMessage(String);
    }
```

but I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: `Object #<Object> has no method 'split'`

Comment: That's no valid [JSON](http://json.org/). If it was, you could just have used `JSON.parse`

Comment: You haven't shown us where message is defined.

Comment: Please see the updated

Answer (score 4):

You've not provided enough code, but it appears as though your `message` is already parsed, and therefore you have an `Object` instead of a `string`.

That said, the JSON data you show in your question is invalid JSON. Not sure if that's the actual response you're getting, or if you altered it.

When you do need to parse JSON, use `JSON.parse()`. No need to do it manually.

---

As I stated above, you're already parsing the JSON.

```
var objResponse = $.parseJSON(messageObj.responseText);
```

Comment: @user2766267: I updated my answer. Like I said, it's already parsed.

Comment: I did message.parse() and thats the error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'parse'. you are right abbout the first part I already have object instead of string because when I debug it in chrome by console.log, that is what I see: Object { getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function,  overrideMimeType: function…} and one of them is responseText that the text that I want to show is inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I see the text that I want to show

Comment: @user2766267: Why did you do `message.parse()`? Where did you get the idea that `message` would have a `parse()` method?

Comment: Sorry, but I am a bit confused. So Now I sould be able to see (text) what I have fetched by messageResponse = message.text; but it prints "undefined" and do not print the whole text

Comment: What are you doing with `messageResponse` after you've assigned `message.text`?

Comment: Thanks for reply, when I did console.log(message) it showed "object" with some value in it. What I cannot undestand is that how can I retrieve "text" which is insde responseText in the Object. Can you guide me with code?

Comment: What are you doing with `messageResponse` after you've assigned `message.text`?

Comment: I also did console.log(JSON.parse(message)); and that is the error I got: Uncaught TypeError: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: regarding your question I did not assign message.text. did I? when I write messageResponse = message and then console.log (message) it shows [object object]

Comment: In your [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727073/issue-in-parsing-json-object/18727098?noredirect=1#comment27597679_18727098) you wrote *"messageResponse = message.text;"*, so I can only assume you performed the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

message is undefined, so far as we can see here.
Did you mean

```
outputString.split(":");
```