# issue in getting a value of Json or object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable like this:

```
{ "Text" : "
            Name:        Useraafsdf
            available       Usef50d0fc138d9r213123
            loggedout       0 

" }
```

and I want to get the value of text. but when I write: `console.log(Response.Text);` I get `"undefined"`. How can I get the value? although I am taking this Response from here: 
`Response = messageObj.responseText;` So Maybe this "Text" is an object and not a json.

Comment: What do you have for `console.log(Response);` ?

Comment: I get the whole Object like: Object{status: 4, ...responseText: { "Text" : "..."}} So there is a responseText and inside it there is Text which I want the value.

Comment: You already asked this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727073/issue-in-parsing-json-object Why are you (again) not posting the entire code?

Answer (score 2):

`messageObj.responseText` is a string, you have to parse it.

```
var Response = JSON.parse(messageObj.responseText);
```

Comment: After trying I realized that messageObj.responseText is an object. but how can I get the value of an object? So what I want to do is to get the value of Text which is an object